# Why do I get a 404 error when I try to fetch from an existing route

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, server, url-routing

I am trying to send data input in my registration page to my mongoDB database through an express.js route but I keep getting a 404: not found error even though I have created this specific route.

server2.js (Setting up server, connecting to mongoDB, and create schema)

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors());
require("dotenv").config({path: "./config.env"});
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

//URI key
const mongoURI = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
console.log(mongoURI);

// Connect to the database
mongoose.connect(mongoURI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
})
    .then(console.log("Connected to MongoDb"))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));




// Define a schema for the data in the "accounts" collection
const accountSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { 
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    min: 2,
    max: 24,

},
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    max: 200,
    lowercase: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    min: 8,
    max: 30,}
});

//we're going to validate the json



// Define a model for the "accounts" collection using the schema
const Account = mongoose.model('Account', accountSchema);

// Example route that finds all accounts in the collection and sends them as JSON


// Start the server
const server = app.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log('Server started on port 4000');
});

server.on("listening", () => {
    console.log("Server is listening");
});

server.on("error", () => {
    console.error("Error starting server", error.message);
});
module.exports = Account;
```

records2.js (creating routes)

```
const express = require("express");
import Account from "../server2";

// recordRoutes is an instance of the express router.
// We use it to define our routes.
// The router will be added as a middleware and will take control of requests starting with path /record.
const accountsRoutes = express.Router();
import Account from "../server2";
import accountModel from "../server2";



   // This route adds a new account


   accountsRoutes.post("http://localhost:4000/accounts/add", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const dePackage = JSON.parse(req);
        console.log("Route has started");
        // Checks if there's an account with the same username or email address
        const existingAccount = await accountModel.findOne({
            $or: [{email:dePackage.email}, {username: dePackage.username}]
        });

        if (existingAccount) {
            return res.status(400).json({message: "An account with that email/username already exists"});
        }
        const newAccount = new Account({
            email: dePackage.email,
            username: dePackage.username,
            password: dePackage.password}
        );
        newAccount.save();

        //find all users
        const allUsers = await User.find();
        console.log(allUsers);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server Error"})
    }
   })
```

registerPage.js (frontend that fetches route on submit)

```
import React, {useState} from "react";



function RegisterPage() {

    // create states to be managed

    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [userName, setUserName] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

    // create routes to handle changes in form

    const handleEmail = (event) => {
        setEmail(event.target.value);
    }

    const handleUsername = (event) => {
        setUserName(event.target.value);
    }

    const handlePassword = (event) => {
        setPassword(event.target.value);
    }

    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/accounts/add", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({email, userName, password}),
            
        });
        console.log(response.body);

        const result = await response.json();
        console.log(result);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <label htmlFor="email">email:</label>
                <input name="email" id="email" type="text" onChange={handleEmail}/>
                <label htmlFor="username">username: </label>
                <input name="username" id="password" type="text" onChange={handleUsername} />
                <br/>
                <label htmlFor="password">password: </label>
                <input name="password" id="password" type="text" onChange={handlePassword}/>
                <br/>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="register" />

            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default RegisterPage;
```

I have tried to see if the server accepts the route, which it clearly didn't and I tried to see if there was a problem with json but it didn't seem to be that. I'm new with backend so help is greatly appreciated :).

Answer (score 2):

There's a problem with your `Express` `POST` route.

**Change this from:**

`accountsRoutes.post("http://localhost:4000/accounts/add", async (req, res) => {});`

**To this:**

`accountsRoutes.post("/accounts/add", async (req, res) => {});`

Additionally, on the frontend you probably should *proxy your React requests* to Express in **development**. Otherwise, React is not aware of Express and is trying to fetch the frontend. Plus your current frontend fetch won't work on a `staging` or `production` environment.

For example, run `npm i --save-dev http-proxy-middleware`, then inside your React app's `src` folder create:

`setupProxy.js`

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

const proxy_urls = ['/api'];

const target = 'http://localhost:4000';

module.exports = function (app) {
  proxy_urls.forEach((url) => {
    app.use(url, createProxyMiddleware({ target }));
  });
};
```

This reserves the `/api` suffix for `React` and funnels all of those /api calls to the backend or better known as a proxy. This file is telling React "all requests to /api should go to `http://localhost:4000` and not `http://localhost:3000`.

Once that's in place your frontend component `fetch` can be modified:

`const response = await fetch("/accounts/add", {});`